# Jenkins osx "cannot run program"

Tags: macos, jenkins

I installed Jenkins om my Snow Leopard laptop. I assigned the user "jenkins" to it's home dir etc. Next, I basically followed [this tutorial](http://jenkins-php.org/).

Now, when I run a build, I get an error:

> /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/projectname/workspace/build.xml:78: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "phpmd": error=2, No such file or directory

Also, he gives the same errors for phploc etc.

When I run phpmd on the commandline, everything is fine. Also when I login as user jenkins with "su jenkins" and I try to run the command on the command line, everything is fine too.

I believe the problem is that Jenkins is unable to find the command. Probably because it's not in the `/usr/bin dir`? I added a `.bash_profile` file with the export path to `/usr/local/bin`, but even that doesn't make a difference. So, anyone know what exactly the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the environment variables (including the PATH) under "System Information" on the page of the slave. You can adjust these variables as well as set tool locations on the slave configuration page. To get to those pages, click on the name of a slave on the main page.

Comment: Ah I see indeed. I also noticed that he is missing the correct path to the tools. I have to add these paths under "configure system" -> "environment variables"?

Comment: For your setup this should be fine. Just keep in mind that with several machines connected to one Jenkins instance, you may have to set that for each slave individually.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to set the PATH environment variable as described above, ie
"manage nodes"->"[node]"->"configure"
and then "name" PATH and "value" /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin

For some reason this did not work - I visited "manage nodes"->"[node]"->"system info"
and the PATH value had not changed and the job continued to not work.

This was with version 1.462 and slave.jar 2.13.

My workaround was to set an explicit path for the tool (git in my case) in the "tool locations" section of the node configuration page.

Comment: I later found that by editing .bashrc "eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)" I could get the path as defined by the contents of /etc/paths and /etc/paths.d/*. However to make jenkins notice the change I also had to kill the running agent (look for a java process running 'slave.jar') and restart it from the jenkins master.

Answer (score 0):

I kindly suggest to replace your phpmd command by a "echo $PATH" so you can see what's in the PATH in the context where you are starting phpmd.